# Use Spider to duplicate Federation Tables on different Hosts

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How can I use Create Table on a Spider node to use Spider as a HA solution for Federation tables. I want all queries to be duplicated on both servers.

### [image: Spider as Federation]

So far I am only able to create a federation to one host using:

```
> CREATE TABLE Table1(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, code VARCHAR(10),
> PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE=SPIDER ENGINE=spider 
> COMMENT='wrapper "mysql",srv "server1"';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer and it was so simple...
in the comment, the "srv" tag can have multiple arguments separeted with spaces.

```
> CREATE TABLE Table1(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, code VARCHAR(10),
> PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE=SPIDER ENGINE=spider 
> COMMENT='wrapper "mysql",srv "server1 server2"';
```